# People picker icons and auto-completion

Tags: 2013, people-picker, user-controls

I am having this problem across different site collections, applications and even farms.

When I have a field of the "User" type in a custom list, the default forms that are created by SharePoint allow for auto-completion on that field. Not only that, they suggest the most commonly used results.

When I create a custom form, though, the user fields don't have auto-completion. Instead, I get a people picker with two buttons to its right (*"check names"* and *"browse"*).

I see the XML for the field in SharePoint Designer but there is not a single property that I can use to control whether the field has auto-completion of the auxiliary icons. How can I set those?

By the way, I cannot create a package with Visual Studio in this case, so developing a custom web part with .NET is not an option. If it is not possible to accomplish what I need to without a .NET custom web part, though, please let me know.